# How to insert values from a one dimensional array given by ETABS into a range in excel using VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, range

I am trying to insert values from  a one dimensional array given to me by a program (ETABS) into a range in Excel using VBA.

This is how the results are returned to you by the ETABS program (please read to understand): http://docs.csiamerica.com/help-files/common-api(from-sap-and-csibridge)/SAP2000_API_Fuctions/Analysis_Results/Results/Analysis_Results_Remarks.htm

Therefore in order for me to insert ONE result into cell "A1" in Excel I just use this code (WHICH WORKS):
`Range("A1").Value = U1(0)`

But if I want to insert ALL of the results into a certain Range I am running into all types of problems..I've tried many codes, but this one seemed to be the most reasonable:
`Range("A1:A" & (NumberResults - 1)).Value = (U1(0) - U1(NumberResults - 1))`

I usually get only the first value repeated all throughout the range instead of the whole set of values.

Does anybody have an idea of how to make all of the values of the array appear in the designated range?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you already tried with a `For` loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the array`U1()` is zero-based:

```
Dim i As Long

For i = LBound(U1) To UBound(U1)
    Range("A" & i + 1).Value = U1(i)
Next i
```